# Use selected value from user in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, user-input

I would like to let the user choose a value from a dropdown menu and, based on the chosen value, display the results. I tried this way, but the code doesn't display any result (even if I choose the last option, which was chosen for return every element). The final score is to let the user pick the max distance and display just the nearest locations. Any suggestion on how to solve it?

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mia_posizione);
} else {
  alert('La geo-localizzazione NON è possibile');
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function aprox(x) {
  if (0.1 < x < 1) {
    var k = x * 10;
    var m = Math.ceil(k);
    var t = m * 100;
    return t + " m";
  } else {
    return Math.ceil(x) + " km";
  }
}

function mia_posizione(position) {
  var select = document.getElementById("distance");
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

  let latitudini = [
    45.830527, 45.879442, 46.017065, 46.045482,

  ];
  let longitudini = [
    9.029344, 8.979577, 8.931969, 8.978964,

  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < latitudini.length; i++) {
    var latLocation = latitudini[i];
    var lonLocation = longitudini[i];
    var latUser = position.coords.latitude;
    var lonUser = position.coords.longitude;
    var R = 6371;
    var dLat = deg2rad(latLocation - latUser);
    var dLon = deg2rad(lonLocation - lonUser);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(latUser)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(latLocation)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var y = R * c;
    var Approssimazione = aprox(y)
    document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("data-index", y);
    const Raggio = document.getElementById(i);
    if (Raggio.dataset.index > value) {
      document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(i).style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

function comparator(a, b) {
  if (a.dataset.index < b.dataset.index)
    return -1;
  if (a.dataset.index > b.dataset.index)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

// Function to sort Data
function SortData() {
  var indexes = document.querySelectorAll("[data-index]");
  var indexesArray = Array.from(indexes);
  let sorted = indexesArray.sort(comparator);
  sorted.forEach(e =>
    document.querySelector("#list").appendChild(e));
}

var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");

MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";

function menutoggle() {
  if (MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px"
  } else {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px"
  }
}
```

```css
.vertical {
  border-left: 6px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gulzar&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="Map">

  <div class="navbar">

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="Cestino.png" width="30px">
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul id="MenuItems">
        <li><a href="">Mappa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contatti</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Missione</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Supporta</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="hamburger-menu.png" width="20px" class="menu" onclick="menutoggle()">
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="row-2">
        <h1>Try it!</h1>
        <p> Now</p>

        <a class="btn" onclick="SortData();"> Find</a>
        <select name="distanze" id="distance">
          <option value="0.5"> 500 m</option>
          <option value="2"> 2 km</option>
          <option value="10"> 10 km</option>
          <option value="50"> 50 km</option>
          <option value="100"> 100 km</option>
          <option value="1000000"> 1000000 km</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row-2">
        <img src="Spazzatura.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>




    <div class="Mappa">

      <ul id="list">

        <li class="index" data-index="2" id=0>
          <div class="via">
            <h2> Closed </h2>
            <h3>
              <a href="" class="Indirizzo"> Hello </a></h3>



            <a href="" class="indirizzo"> Info </a></p>
            <br>
            <img src="water.png"> <img src="wine.png"> <img src="wood.png"> <img src="shirt.png"><img src="battery.png"><img src="documents.png"><img src="television.png"> <img src="canned-food.png"></div>
        </li>
        <br>

        <li class="index" data-index="1" id=1>
          <div id=1> </div>
          <div class="via">
            <h2> Hello</h2>
            <h3>
              <a href="" class="Indirizzo"> My name </a></h3>



            <a href="" class="indirizzo"> Info </a></p>
            <br>
            <img src="water.png"> <img src="wine.png"> <img src="wood.png"> <img src="shirt.png"><img src="battery.png"><img src="documents.png"><img src="television.png"><img src="canned-food.png"></div>
        </li>

        <br>
        <li class="index" data-index="3" id=2>
          <h3 id=2> </h3>
          <div class="via">
            <h2> Hi </h2>
            <h3>
              <a href="" class="Indirizzo"> Good Morning </a></h3>

            <p>
              <a href="" class="indirizzo"> Info </a></p>
            <br>
            <img src="water.png"> <img src="wine.png"> <img src="wood.png"> <img src="battery.png"><img src="documents.png"><img src="television.png"> <img src="canned-food.png"> <img src="leaf.png"></div>
        </li>

        <br>
        <li class="index" data-index="3" id=3>
          <h3 id=3> </h3>
          <div class="via">
            <h2>
              Good afternoon</h2>
            <h3>
              <a href="" class="Indirizzo"> Hello </a></h3>

            <p>
              <a href="" class="indirizzo"> Info </a></p>
            <br>
            <img src="water.png"> <img src="wine.png"> <img src="wood.png"> <img src="battery.png"><img src="documents.png"><img src="television.png"> <img src="canned-food.png"> <img src="leaf.png"></div>
        </li>



      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Computers are dumb. If you don't tell the `<select>` it is supposed to do something when it's value changes, it won't do anything. So bind and [eventhandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) to the select.

Comment: You have invalid HTML; the *only* valid child of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) is `<li>`, the `<br>`  is not valid there.